# some questions about tensorflow GradientDescentOptimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I tried to test my code use tensorflow, I set GradientDescentOptimizer learning rate equal to 1 and output Wx1 old weight, new weight, and gradients. but the **new weight != old weight - 1*gradients**, I don't why can cause this situation.

1. Wx1 old value [[-0.0016595601,....]]
2. grads [[-0.02760417,....]]
3. Wx1 new value [[-0.0016706019,....]]

batch data X dimension is 500*1000 and Y dimension is 500*30. Wx1 dimension is 1000*512 and grads dimension is also 1000*512

```
loss = net.loss(x, y, keep_prob)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1).minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init)
   for X, Y, tot in data.next_batch('train'):
       feed_dict = {x: X,
                    y: Y}
       Wx1 = net.Wx1
       Wx1_val_old = sess.run(Wx1)
       grads = sess.run(tf.gradients(loss, [Wx1]), feed_dict=feed_dict)[0]
       sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
       Wx1_val_new = sess.run(Wx1)
```

Comment: I solved this problem, but still I don't know why.